# What is the local extrema of a Greatest Integer Function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to find the local extrema of Greatest Integer Function f(x)=int(x). Because the function has many constant points, would there be infinitely many local extrema? Also, how would one find the continuity, asymptotes, and end behavior? Thanks

Comment: Yes, every point of the function is a local extremum. It is continuous where it is constant - i.e., everywhere except at integers.

Comment: Which of the above have you been able to find? By drawing the graph, at least you would have an idea of all of them, right? So you would need to make it rigorous, are you having trouble there?